# Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier

Tags: matlab, fopen

I'm trying to read a sequence of files with `textscan`, but I keep getting this error:

> Error using textscan
>   Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

My code is:

```
fd = fopen(['D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\' files(id).name],'rt');
line = textscan(fd, '%s %f %d %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
```

When I try to see the output of `['D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\' files(id).name]` it returns the path correctly:

> D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\00000000.png

Also command `fopen(D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\00000000.png)` returns **3** or **4** or etc.

But command `fopen(['D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\' files(id).name])` returns **-1**.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Just for reference, on my system both commands work and don't return **-1** (with or without string concatenation). I am on Linux though, and it seems you are on Windows.

Comment: @UJIN yes I am using windows. The second command is in a **for loop**, so I can't use it like the first one.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you need to use the second version. Unfortunately I can't reproduce the behavior you are experiencing, both are working fine for me. You will have to wait someone who can, and probably who uses Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you are trying to open a .png file in text mode.
Try `fd = fopen( file_name, 'r')`, or in your example:

```
fd = fopen(['D:\Thesis\Data\vedai_co_75_25\train\labels\' files(id).name],'r');
```

On Windows, opening the wrong files in text mode can cause issues. The help of `fopen` states:

> (On Unix, text and
>       binary mode are the same, so this has no effect.  On PC systems
>       this is critical.)

Comment: Yes, must definitely be this. I was also a bit puzzled when I saw the 'rt' in `fopen` for an image, but then I tested on Ubuntu and it didn't return any error.

Comment: Yes, thanks for testing it on Linux. That has lead me to my assumption.

Comment: I'm really sorry for this mistake. I should have used `txtfiles` instead of `files`. The problem solved. Thanks a lot